# Which capacitors to use with voltage regulator IC such as 7805?

Tags: capacitor, voltage-regulator, 7805, lm78xx, smoothing-capacitor

Many of the tutorials suggest to use a large smoothing capacitor (tens and even hundreds of uF) with a full wave rectifier but the datasheets of the voltage regulators and some tutorials suggest only a 0.33uF capacitor to be used for smoothing the input voltage. I am puzzled as there is really a big difference.

Moreover, what if we use a large capacitor such as 10uF instead of 0.1uF after the voltage regulator?

Comment: The large smoothing capacitor serves a different purpose that the 0.33 uF capacitor at the input of the 7805. There is no harm in having **both** where the 0.33 uF is close to the 7805. Regarding the capacitor at the output of the 7805: do what is suggested in the datasheet of the 7805.

Comment: Yes, it should be noted that it is often recommended to use both a large electrolytic and a small paper capacitor or some such (in parallel), since electrolytics tend to have a smidgen of inductance and series resistance, making them less than ideal for filtering high frequencies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Many of the tutorials suggest to use a large smoothing capacitor (tens and even hundreds of uF) with a full wave rectifier

An interesting property of AC voltage is that it goes down to zero twice per cycle, which means if you use a transformer and a rectifier, you need a capacitor large enough after the rectifier to act as temporary energy storage during the parts of the period where the AC voltage is too low.

Basically, \$ dv/dt = i/C \$ so you take the max post-rectifier voltage and the min allowed voltage at the input of the regulator, which gives you max allowed voltage drop, divide by one half period, you get your max dv/dt, you know the max i, you get the minimum C value to use. Add a wide safety factor.

> but the datasheets of the voltage regulators and some tutorials suggest only a 0.33uF capacitor to be used for smoothing the input voltage.

That's to keep the regulator stable if you feed it from a DC power supply.

Regulators can react badly to too much inductance in the supply (ie, long wires) so a local small value cap keeps this power supply impedance down. Use whatever ceramic cap of suitable voltage like 100nF or 1µF, value doesn't matter as long as it's enough, what matters is that it is placed close to the regulator.

> Moreover, what if we use a large capacitor such as 10uF instead of 0.1uF after the voltage regulator?

Some regulators are conditionally stable depending on output cap value and ESR, so reading the datasheet is necessary. 7805 isn't picky though. A larger output cap will probably just give better transient response.

Comment: So a 10uF capacitor after the regulator is Ok to go with?

Answer (score 4):

The definition in the datasheet is mostly to prevent the regulator to get into a state where it starts to oscillate. If your power source has "large" output capacitors and is reasonably close to your regulator, you can get away even without an input cap.
The issue, why you need the caps is the inductivity of the connectrion to the source.

So in most cases a small cap is enough.

Also, many of the "big capacitor" suggestions are old experience when the source of the voltage was rectified line frequency (Pulsing at 50/60Hz with a single diode rectifier or 100/120Hz with a full bridge rectifier). And to get a really smooth output you wanted to minimize that input ripple, thus the big caps. But the 78xx/79xx are very well optimized to suppress that 50-120Hz noise. Better at it than supressing the 20-200kHz ripples and spikes they get from modern switching power supplies.

In my latest design I included an inductivity in front of the 7805 and added a small input capacitor for that reason (make sure not to build an oscillator that way, you might need to dampen it with a resistor to reduce Q).

So, "small" cap really close to the regulator (on both sides) is enough in most cases.

If you have special requirements (long leads from the power source and quickly changing current consumption for example) you're better off simulating the setup (with wiring included) anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You have better load regulation, less ripple and better transient response. These days really big capacitors are not really used that much since we have fast regulators.

A big capacitor is useful if you have a bridge and a load which is *not* powered by a regulator since it can only relay on the cap for ripple suppression (like motors and such). A typical rule of thumb is 1000µF for each Ampere of load but it depends on the loads, too.